# Foreach loop through multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have this set of data that I get from `html` form. It is basically a multidimensional array.

**Data**

```
array(3) {
  ["r1"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  ["r2"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "96"
  }
  ["tekma_id"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "7"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

**Problem:** What i want to do, is to go over this array and for each iteration create a data variable(`array`).

**So for example:**

First iteration:

```
$data = array(
   'r1' => '2'
   'r2' => '5'
   'tekma_id' => '7'
)
```

Second iteration:

```
$data = array(
   'r1' => '4'
   'r2' => '96'
   'tekma_id' => '8'
)
```

I've tried with this:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $index => $v) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "r1: $v";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "r2: $v";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "tekma_id: $v";
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. Sorry for my bad english and thanks for any help.
Cheers!

Comment: Are `r1`, `r2` and `tekma_id` fixed or dynamic indexes?

Comment: @hjpotter92 they come from inputs with names r1[], r2[] and tekma_id[]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
$array = array(
    'r1' => array(2, 4),
    'r2' => array(5, 96),
    'tekma_id' => array(7, 8));

$keys = array_keys($data);
$iterations = count($array[$keys[0]]);

for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
    $data = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $value[$i];
    }
    print_r($data);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [r1] => 2
    [r2] => 5
    [tekma_id] => 7
)
Array
(
    [r1] => 4
    [r2] => 96
    [tekma_id] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$keys = array_keys($data);
$count = count(array_shift(array_values($data)));

for ($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $result[$key] = $data[$key][$i];
    }
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: +1 Just one note - in strict mode, `array_shift()` will throw an error in this case since the argument is not a variable.